# Can javascript access the binary data in an image that's loaded via <img src=

Tags: javascript, image

if I have something like

```
<img src="x.jpg" id=i>
```

is there away to access the binary using something like getElementById("i").something ?

Comment: You can do it with the canvas API, but only if you're loading the image from the same domain as the enclosing page.

Comment: If it's same-origin you can paint it in a canvas and get the pixel data, but I'm not sure about binary data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript

Comment: As Oriol said. If you have pixel data (in canvas) these are 8bit numbers, you can access them as binary. Why?

Comment: You might be able to do it by sending an additional XMLHTTPRequest. You SHOULD AFAIK get the "binary" back.

Comment: There is also a base64 pattern that you can obtain. Google DataURL .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an [MDN demo](http://mdn.github.io/promises-test/):

They show in the below example how to fetch an image using an XHR request wrapped in a Promise. (you don't really need the promise part, but it's cool).

Just make sure the images are on the same domain which this code runs on, or wrap with [JSONP](http://json-p.org/).

And to your question, you could iterate on all the images on the page, and run the `imgLoad` function with their `src`, to get the data. I can't think of a way to access the data of an image that was already downloaded through the browser's own mechanism (src='...')

```
function imgLoad(url) {
    // Create new promise with the Promise() constructor;
    // This has as its argument a function
    // with two parameters, resolve and reject
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      // Standard XHR to load an image
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open('GET', url);
      request.responseType = 'blob';

      // When the request loads, check whether it was successful
      request.onload = function() {
        if (request.status === 200) {
        // If successful, resolve the promise by passing back the request response
          resolve(request.response);
        } else {
        // If it fails, reject the promise with a error message
          reject(Error('Error code:' + request.statusText));
        }
      };

      request.onerror = function() {
      // Also deal with the case when the entire request fails to begin with
      // This is probably a network error, so reject the promise with a message
          reject(Error('There was a network error.'));
      };

      // Send the request
      request.send();
    });
}

// Get a reference to the body element, and create a new image object
var body = document.querySelector('body');
var myImage = new Image();

// Call the function with the URL we want to load, but then chain the
// promise then() method on to the end of it. This contains two callbacks
imgLoad('myLittleVader.jpg')
    .then(function(response) {
        // The first runs when the promise resolves, with the request.reponse
        // specified within the resolve() method.
        var imageURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(response);
        myImage.src = imageURL;
        body.appendChild(myImage);
        // The second runs when the promise
        // is rejected, and logs the Error specified with the reject() method.
    }, 
    function(Error) {
        console.log(Error);
    });
```